# Firebase Database Rules: can't write to database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I tried to set some important write persmissions but I can't solve my problem. I got told that, if I add a write-rule to room, then I overwrite my room/$roomID/ingame rule.

**What I'm trying to do is**

Creating a **room** by auth users. 
Set/update **ingame** of a room only by the creator of the room. *(That works)*

**Rules**:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    "user": {
      ".indexOn": "displayname"
    },
    "room": {
      "$roomID": {
        "ingame":{
            ".write": "data.parent().child('creatorUid').val() == auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How I call to create a **new room**:

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser
dbRoomRef.push().then((room) => {
    room.set({
        creatorUid: user.uid,
            ingame: false,
        })
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message)
    }
)
```

**Error message** (as expected):

`FIREBASE WARNING: set at /room/-L572bnuRv0_vntko-Bd failed: permission_denied`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages says that you're trying to write `/room/-L572bnuRv0_vntko-Bd` and have no permission to write there. That is correct, since your rules only give permission to write to `/room/-L572bnuRv0_vntko-Bd/ingame`.

If `creatorUid` is already set when you create the room, you don't have to include it in your write statement and can just do:

```
room.child("ingame").set(false);
```

If you're trying to allow everyone to create a new room (or write to an existing room) as long as they are the owner, you need to set your rules one level higher:

```
"room": {
  "$roomID": {
    ".write": "newData.child('creatorUid').val() == auth.uid"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Frank! That was what I was looking for. I got it. Have a nice day.